What is the definition of and quantifier order in consistency for one-step methods?
Consider the usual Cauchy IVP $y = f(x, y)$ with $y(x_0) = y_0$, satisfying assumptions of Picard's theorem in a rectangle $D$.
A one-step method is essentially
$$y_{n+1} = y_{n} + h \Phi(x_n, y_n; h),$$
where $x_k = x_0 + k h$, and assume $\Phi$ is continuous. The $n$th local (truncation) error is defined as
$$T_n(h; y) = T_n = \frac{1}{h} (y(x_{n+1}) - y(x_n)) - \Phi(x_n, y_n; h).$$
When is the one-step method given above called consistent? In Süli, Mayers An introduction to numerical analysis (2014), on page 321 it states, essentially, that consistency holds when

for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a positive $h(\varepsilon)$ for which $|T_n| < \varepsilon$ for $ 0 < h < h(\varepsilon)$ and any pair of points $(x_n, y(x_n))$, $(x_{n+1}, y_{n+1})$ on any solution curve in $D$.

Is this just trying to say that for any appopriate rectangle $D$ (with any chosen $x_0$ satisfying Picard) ...

for all $n$ we have $\lim_{h\to 0}{T_n} = 0$? OR more weakly
for all $n$ up to some cut-off $N$, claiming consistency up to $N$, as in $\lim_{h\to 0}{\max_{1\leq n \leq N} T_n} = 0$ for some fixed $N$? OR uniformly
should the $h(\varepsilon)$ be good enough for any $n$ big enough, otherwise independent of $n$? OR
something else, perhaps some combination of $h \to 0$ and $n \to +\infty$?


These are astute observations.
I'm not sure what advantage this limit definition has. Other sources give the much shorter $\Phi(x,y;0)=f(x,y)$. Which amounts to the recombination coefficients $b_i$ summing to $1$. Under continuity of $\Phi$ and $y(x)$ being a solution, this is equivalent.
Consistency is a property of the method, not of the ODE, its domain or its solutions. The index $n$ is misplaced here.

1.-4.) The index $n$ should play no role in the definition of this property, the index $n$ makes no sense in this place. The inputs to the local truncation error should stay at the same location. To that end, $n$ needs to be coupled to $h$, as you noticed, and $h\to0$ is considered. But there need not be some intricate construction to connect this to some unspecified far-away initial point. One can always consider the local point as initial point.

So if one wants a limit definition, it should be that for any continuous ODE function $f$ and any point $(x_o,y_o)$ in its domain and the local solution $y(x)$ through that point
$$
T(x,y;h)=\frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{h}-\Phi_f(x,y(x);h)=o(h^0).
$$
Which can be formulated shorter as the method function $\Phi_f$ being continuous (which follows usually from its construction) and
$$
T(x,y;0)=f(x,y(x))-\Phi_f(x,y(x);0)=0.
$$

Thank you for the helpful response. Did you mean to say that $T(x, y; h)$ is $\mathrm{o}(1)$, in other words $h T(x, y; h)$ is $\mathrm{o}(h)$? So it is something like «For any $f$ with sufficient smoothness and any $(x_o, y_o)$ in its domain, for the (unique) solution $y$ through this point it is the case that for all $x$ in the domain of $y$ we have $\lim_{h\to 0}{T(x, y; h)} = 0$?»

Yes, of course. All the other things are continuity in $h$ at $h=0$ with value $0$, as also written in the answer.

And is it a similar story for the term «one-step method has order of accuracy $p$», with minor modifications? So «p is supremum such that for all smooth enough $f$ , with $\Phi_f$ continuous (at $0$), and any $(x_o, y_o)$ in the domain of $f$, for the (unique) solution $y$ through this point it is the case that for all $x$ in the domain of $y$ we have that $T(x, y; h)$ is $\mathrm{O}(h^p)$?» This is a similar term that is written using the index $n$ in the book (pages 323-324)

Yes, that also is a local property mainly of the method that is valid for all sufficiently smooth ODE problems. In some situations the local order can be higher in isolated points, roots of the leading error coefficient, so $p$ is kind of an essential supremum.

Thanks again for your help! I do appreciate it.
